# How disabled log apache for image file missing?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

**How can we specify extensions file to filter it in log error of apache?**

My error.log fills with :

> [Thu Nov 27 22:42:42 2014] [error] [client 42.42.42.42] File does not exist: /var/www/site/images/foo.PNG

In my case, I want avoid .png, .jpg, .gif to error log when they are missing.

How can I do that?

Comment: When viewing the logs, you can exclude the unwanted noise with a command like `tail -f /var/log/httpd/error.log | egrep -v "JPG|jpg|gif|png"`. `egrep -v` will exclude the pattern from the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the best idea would of course be to fix the site contents so there are no broken image links ;)

With regards to the [`ErrorLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#errorlog):

> It is not possible to customize the error log by adding or removing information.

So you can't exclude specific error messages. It is possible to increase or reduce the verbosity of the ErrorLog with the [`LogLevel`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel) directive though. For example:

```
LogLevel crit
ErrorLog error_log
```

The better option might be to set a rewrite rule that redirects broken image to a stock image e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ 
RewriteRule (.*) /images/broken-image.png [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

shellcommand that will fix the ErrorLog (which you can't customize)

```
touch /var/www/site/images/foo.PNG
```

To not have that empty file show up in your CustomLog use:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "foo\.png$" dontlog
CustomLog log/access_example.com.log env=!dontlog
```

Comment: I need general solution. Not for one specific file. If I have 100 images with random name, I need to ignore it too.